# Expose local network resources with Microsoft technologies

Tags: c#, .net, iis, local, intranet

There is an application hosted on IIS which is only accessible on the local network (intranet). But I need to expose one site to the internet. 
Lets say it is:
http://localnetwork/site?param=value

So I need to create an application which would use a public ip address and could act as a middle man between outside users and that local network site.

Is it possible and how it is done (at least, how is it called)?

Comment: You are talking about proxies and routers. This isn't a programming question. If you don't know how to do this, it's better/safer to host the site on a hoster. Otherwise you *will* be hacked. Eg at the very *least* you'll need a firewall in front of your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting up a reverse proxy. This basically means you have a publicly accessible IIS server (or site), which will redirect the request to that site to a site protected behind your firewall. 
Look at these articles:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis
- http://www.myconnectionserver.com/support/tutorials/v90/iisProxy/index.html
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr/